# Update failed with "Some index files failed to download"

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Everytime I do a `sudo apt-get update` I get this error below

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com yakkety InRelease                                                                   
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                           
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease                                                     
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                             
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                           
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                 
Err:8 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                         
  Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (202.90.159.172), connection timed out
Err:9 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:10 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (202.90.159.172), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.10 LTS, it was working yesterday.

Comment: what is the dns that you use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is obvious you can't connect to URL `ph.archive.ubuntu.com`
so go to `/etc/apt/` and search for `ph.archive.ubuntu.com` and disable it by comment or delete

```
cd /etc/apt/
sudo grep -ir 'ph.archive.ubuntu.com' ./
```

then open the file that contain it and disable it.

Comment: Hmm let me see Ill try

Comment: It worked, it seemed to refresh when I add repository again, thanks!